# Repeated permutation in a 2D space

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinatorics, counting, discrete-mathematics

Given a set of items, let's say, number 1-6. Find the permutations (to be precise, the number of different permutations) using these items. Every item can be used more than once. The limitation is, two adjacent items should not be the same. I use '#' to represent the position where the item can be placed.

Let's begin with an example in a 1D space. The solution is straightforward. We have 6 choices for the first position, and 5 for the next ones.

```
Q: '###'
A: 6*5*5=150
```

---

But I find it's much difficult if we consider the situation in a 2D space. In a 2D space, the adjecent item is the one on the top, bottom, left or right.

```
Q: '##
    # '
A: 6*5*5=150
```

This one is just like in a 1D space.

```
Q: '##
    ##'
A: 6*5*(4*4+1*5)=630
```

Things go complicated.

```
Q: '###
    ###'
A: ???
Q: '###
    ###
    ###'
A: ???
```

I cannot give a solution.

---

Is there an effective method to solve the problem? And what if the space is expanded to 100*100?

I've tried to solve it by a program, a brute-force 6^n traversal (n is the number of positions). Any other good ideas?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why isn't your original "Q: '###'" "A: 6*5*4=120"?  How did you get 6*5*5?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Every item can be used **more than once**, and two adjacent items should not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This website gives the math for calculating permutations.  From there it's straightforward to code it, however it's important to note that permutations involve factorials which grow to unmanageable numbers VERY fast.  Your 100x100 example is likely not possible as the numbers would be monstrous.

https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/discrete-mathematics-and-probability/permutations-and-combinations

Comment: Thanks but this website is not what I want.